# css transition height not effecting text

Tags: html, css

I have applied a height transition to a box, but it just effects the border and not the text within. I want the text to slowly shrink with the box, how can I achieve a slow transition to hide the text?

code :

```
<div class="test">
this is my test
</div>
```

css:

```
.test {
    transition: height 2s, ease-in;
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

    .test:hover{
        height: 1px;
    }
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mx0yh9cs/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add overflow: hidden;

```
.test {
    transition: height 2s, ease-in;
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I was about to post this.

Comment: @Scimonster easy one :P